# Data is not loading in CiviHR

Tags: civihr

In the CiviHR installation, data is not displaying in self service portal. In menu like My Leave under self portal showing angular js error in console.

[image]

But in HR menu I'm able to see all my contacts. there are no errors at all.

This installation is hosted in DigitalOcean 2GB RAM and 2CPU.

Is CiviHR required more RAM?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if directory path and resource url is set for extension?

Comment: Path is define as : [civicrm.files]/ext/   but I have directory there is no data.

Comment: is that the current path if extension?

Comment: Yes, I have used command line installation so this path is already defined in that. https://github.com/compucorp/civihr-installer